# How do I shift column of matrix (NOT NUMPY) to the last column?

Tags: python, list, matrix

Say I have a regular matrix (meaning a matrix that is not numpy) as such:

```
[['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
 [5, 6, 8, 2, 6]
 [2, 9, 3, 3, 6]
 [7, 1, 9, 3, 5]]
```

I want to shift column 2 of the matrix to the last column:

```
[['A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A2']
 [5, 8, 2, 6, 6]
 [2, 3, 3, 6, 9]
 [7, 9, 3, 5, 1]]
```

How exactly do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
col2 = []
for item in mylist:
    col2.append(item[1])
    del item[1]
for item in col2:
    mylist.insert(4, item)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, in a convenient function!

Please note the matrix is 0 indexed!!

```
In [12]: arr = [['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
    ...:  [5, 6, 8, 2, 6],
    ...:  [2, 9, 3, 3, 6],
    ...:  [7, 1, 9, 3, 5]]
    ...:

In [15]: def swap_col(arr, fr, to):
    ...:     new_arr = []
    ...:     for row in arr:
    ...:         row[to], row[fr] = row[fr], row[to]
    ...:         new_arr.append(row)
    ...:     return new_arr

In [14]: swap_col(arr, 1, 4)
Out[14]:
[['A1', 'A5', 'A3', 'A4', 'A2'],
 [5, 6, 8, 2, 6],
 [2, 6, 3, 3, 9],
 [7, 5, 9, 3, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [80]: alist = [['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'], 
    ...:  [5, 6, 8, 2, 6], 
    ...:  [2, 9, 3, 3, 6], 
    ...:  [7, 1, 9, 3, 5]]
```

There's a well know idiom that 'transposes' a list matrix:

```
In [86]: x = list(zip(*alist))                                                                               
In [87]: x                                                                                                   
Out[87]: 
[('A1', 5, 2, 7),
 ('A2', 6, 9, 1),
 ('A3', 8, 3, 9),
 ('A4', 2, 3, 3),
 ('A5', 6, 6, 5)]
```

then we can `pop` off the relevant list, and concatenate it on the end:

```
In [88]: p = x.pop(1)                                                                                        
In [89]: p                                                                                                   
Out[89]: ('A2', 6, 9, 1)
In [90]: x = x+[p]                                                                                           
In [91]: x                                                                                                   
Out[91]: 
[('A1', 5, 2, 7),
 ('A3', 8, 3, 9),
 ('A4', 2, 3, 3),
 ('A5', 6, 6, 5),
 ('A2', 6, 9, 1)]
```

then transpose back:

```
In [92]: newlist = list(zip(*x))                                                                             
In [93]: newlist                                                                                             
Out[93]: 
[('A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A2'),
 (5, 8, 2, 6, 6),
 (2, 3, 3, 6, 9),
 (7, 9, 3, 5, 1)]
```

This is a case where the object array version can be handy:

```
In [96]: arr = np.array(alist, object)                                                                       
In [97]: arr                                                                                                 
Out[97]: 
array([['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5'],
       [5, 6, 8, 2, 6],
       [2, 9, 3, 3, 6],
       [7, 1, 9, 3, 5]], dtype=object)
In [102]: np.concatenate([arr[:,[0]],arr[:,2:], arr[:,[1]]], axis=1)                                         
Out[102]: 
array([['A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A2'],
       [5, 8, 2, 6, 6],
       [2, 3, 3, 6, 9],
       [7, 9, 3, 5, 1]], dtype=object)
In [103]: _.tolist()                                                                                         
Out[103]: 
[['A1', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'A2'],
 [5, 8, 2, 6, 6],
 [2, 3, 3, 6, 9],
 [7, 9, 3, 5, 1]]
```